# Spring-Thymeleaf How to invoke with EL an action method from a Bean

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I am using Spring/SpringMVC 5.x version, with Thymeleaf and Bootstrap on Tomcat server.

I need to ask something that maybe it might look to you very "st@pid" question.

In my html view I have the following button or a link:

```
<input type="button" .../>
<a .../>
```

I don't need to submit something, so I just use a simple button, so I think I don't need any form for it (except if I need for this).

In this html view (because of the thymeleaf library I added in the html tag), I need to add somehow,
(but I don't know how), to this button or in the link, an expression of Spring EL or Thymeleaf EL, so I can invoke a method from a
Spring bean, that I passed in the view, via a model which I added in my controller, e.g.:

```
${myBean.doSomething()
// or
${myBean.doSomething(parameters)
```

If this is not understandable I can update my question with some code (I believe that Spring developers
understand what I am talking about).

I don't know how to pass this expression. What attribute of button or link tag to use?
I used "action" attribute for the button:

```
<input type="button" th:action="${myBean.doSomething()".../>
```

or "href" attribute in the link tag:

```
<a th:href= "${myBean.getStringUrlAndDoSomething()"/>
```

***Very significant info***

When I started my tomcat running the page, the actions in the EL are run successfuly on the load of the page. When I pressed the button or the link nothing happened.

I know that I cannot use "onclick" attribute because there we write JS code.
But I need to run Java Spring code.

Any ideas about solving my problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot. A button should trigger a form submit or ajax request to execute an action on the server. Using a simple EL expression won't work.

Comment: Like @M.Deinum states, you need a form or an ajax request. If you don't like to write JavaScript for that request, you can look at https://htmx.org/ which allows to trigger an ajax request from html attributes.

Comment: "When I started my tomcat running the page, the actions in the EL are run successfuly on the load of the page. When I pressed the button or the link nothing happened." -> This is normal as Thymeleaf executes that code once when it turns the template into HTML on the server.

Comment: Hello all. Thanks for your comments. My problem is that I have a button (I can put it as a link, this is not a problem), which I want to use it as language switcher. The backend staff is done. The language can switch easilly. I need to make only the button. The button has an image as background the country flag. Ok, I need with code to press it and switch flag and the locale as well. In this case I made it as a link, because I need with the <a th:href="@{?lang=en}"/> to call a method from the bean which switshes from "?lang=en" to "?lang=el" and the opposite....

Comment: ...  How can I do these things, in this case I cannot control them from bean methods? Thanks

Comment: I will try to put this button/link though in a form and try to see if this works

Comment: I finally found a solution and I will post it little bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice of the @M.Deinum, @Wim Deblauwe, and I did not use
a button for this job. Button needs a form to work.

That is why I used a link, where the method from the bean is called like a charm, like
the following snippet:

```
<div class="blabla">
    <div class="blablabla" th:text="|#{change_lang} EN/GR:|"></div>
    <a class="bla" th:href="${localeService.switchLocale()}">
        <div th:class="|${localeService.loadCss()}_blabla|"></div>
    </a>
    <span th:text="${#locale.getLanguage()}"></span>
</div>
```

And next is a snippet from the bean:

```
public String switchLocale() {

        locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();

        if (locale.getLanguage().equals("en")) {
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(EN_LOCALE);
            return "?lang=el";
        } else if (locale.getLanguage().equals("el")) {
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(GR_LOCALE);
            return "?lang=en";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

So, the code from the bean IS invoked successfuly. I guess this is the solution to my issue.

Thanks a lot from the 2 people @M.Deinum, @Wim Deblauwe, who advised me.